# jQuery dialog options doesn't re-size dynamically

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to resize the dialog dynamically just before I open it, but this doesn't work.

**EDIT:**
I found the problem me editing the code in the wrong place. 
This works as expected:

```
   $("#thxboxMd").dialog("option", { height: 400 });
   $("#thxboxMd").dialog("open");
```

Rest:

```
$("#thxboxMd").dialog({
                    resizable: false,
                    height: 200,
                    width: 400,
                    autoOpen: false,
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                        "close": function () {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Can we see the rest of the relevant code for initializing the dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$("#thxboxMd").dialog("option", "height", 400);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/b7ZrG/)**.

Comment: Thanks! I found the problem me editing the code in the wrong place. OP works as expected; 
                            $("#thxboxMd").dialog("option", { height: 400 });
                            $("#thxboxMd").dialog("open");

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$("#thxboxMd").dialog("option", height, 400);
```